# DatePicker with data annotation in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, model-view-controller, datepicker

I'm using data annotation in my model for a date picker.

**Model:**

```
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first time when I am adding date to database it shows me calendar(without time).[image]

next when I want to make changes in my records it does not show calendar. What can I change/add for this ?

And also it has validation for format. When I add date it is dd/mm/yyyy and when I'm making changes it only validates yyyy/mm/dd. How can I change it?

This is quite confusing and rare case and I'm hope you can help me.

Comment: Try `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`. The problem is when you return saved date. If not saved it working like a charm. Just set format for date when you displaying it.

Comment: I recommend that you use bootstrap datepicker instead of browser specific picker. Because when you open your website in internet explorer, you won't be able to see this date picker.
Here is the link of bootstrap datepicker.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: you can also specify, your date format during initiation of the bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki it does not work.

Comment: @Saadi Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: Did you see difference between IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I solved it putting a script of validation for verify the browser (Google's Chrome works fine and no needs that)

```
 var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if (!isChrome) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#IdOfDivThatYouNedd").datepicker();
        });
    }
```

For validation you can use this dataanotation:

`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "date is not a corret format")]`